# Android crashing on specific device - caused by int64 allocation

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm having a problem that only seems to happen on my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet running Android OS 3.1. I am running a native app using the NDK. The application runs fine in the emulator and on other devices.

Whenever I allocate an int64_t (defined as long long) I get a SIGILL crash with signal (4). As an example these lines will crash on the device.

```
int64_t i = 0; 
long long j = 0;
```

I should note, the application runs fine, I can see menus rendering correctly, animating and waiting for input. When I touch, I allocate int64 variables for the timestamps, this is when the crash occurs. Regardless of where I allocate an int64 in this app, I get a crash.

The strange thing is, I loaded up the native-activity sample that comes with the NDK and tried allocating the above data types and it works fine. Both applications have the same Application.mk and very similar Android.mk files. I have also tried cleaning the project.

I am really unsure of what to look at next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. This project is a port from an iOS project which has some NEON math classes in it. We use the following flags for NEON support:

```
 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

We used the same flags in the Android project initially which worked initially. Although as soon as we got a new test device (Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet) we started getting the crash as above. Since building for armeabi-v5 worked and doesn't use NEON I knew it was related. It turns out there are better ways to compile for NEON for Android than using the above flags. I removed the above flags so that our Android.mk looks like so:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
     LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -DHAS_NEON=1
     MY_SRC_FILES   += myfile.cpp.neon
else
     LOCAL_CFLAGS   += -DHAS_NEON=0
     MY_SRC_FILES   += myfile.cpp
endif
```

This means that only the files that actually need to be built for NEON are. The processor inside the Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet (Nvidia Tegra 2) doesn't support NEON so clearly building all files with NEON support was generating the instructions in a way which the processor didn't like.

Thanks for Keith for suggesting that I try the other architectures which led me to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your compiler is generating 64-bit instructions that are not implemented by the processor on your machine.  Are you cross-compiling?  If so, make sure you're targeting the correct version of the ARM (x86?) chip in your tablet.

Comment: I don't think I am cross-compiling. I am only using one abi in the Application.mk file which is armeabi-v7a (off the top of my head). Is there something else I need to check? I am using the same build settings as another project where these data types work on the device.

Comment: Try building for v6 or v5 and see if that helps.

Comment: I built for armeabi (v5) which worked fine. I'm doing some more digging into the cause of this but if I can only target v5 I will miss out on NEON support among other things. I'm leaving the question open because I don't think I should be limited to v5.